# Vendor Creation error in ax 2012

Tags: axapta, x++

i get this error "Field vendor name must be filled" when trying to create a new vendor and specifying a vendor name and all required fields.

Comment: standard code? or do you perform any change in code? can you share the code?

Answer (score 0):

try to check about related Tables (DirPartyTable - VendTable etc) if this field is Mandatory , or if in yourForm is mandatory too.

To usually, standard, the *VendorName* is field on `DirPartyTable.Name` , `VendTable` is related on `DirPartyTable`by field **Party**

```
VendTable.Party == DirPartyTable.RecId
```

Try to check if you fill this field in someway.
Enjoy!